# NSString - max 1 decimal of a float

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumberformatter

I would like to use a float in a NSString. I used the stringWithFormat and a %f to integrate my float into the NSString. The problem is that I would like to display only one decimal (%.1f) but when there is no decimals I don't want to display a '.0' .

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer with NSNumberFormatter and setMaximumFractionDigits, then:

```
[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:myNumber]
```

Thanks to everyone especially @falconcreek

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormat:@"#,##0.#"];
NSNumber *oneThousand = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1000.0];
NSNumber *fivePointSevenFive = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.75];

NSLog(@"1000.0 formatted: %@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:oneThousand]);
NSLog(@"5.75 formatted: %@", [numberForatter stringFromNumber:fivePointSevenFive]);
```

There is a link in Apple's Data Formatting Programming Guide to the formatting standards.
Handy Reference [Number Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Number_Format_Patterns)

Comment: such a useful method. time to file a feature request on the bug reporter.

Answer (score 1):

you could use %g like this

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat: @"test: %g", (float)1.2]);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat: @"test: %g", (float)1])
```

Answer (score 0):

NSNumberFormatter has changed a little bit recently.  Here is an example of getting two significant digits rounding:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
[numberFormatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[numberFormatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:2];
```

And here's [a link](http://nshipster.com/nsformatter/) to a good, recent resource.